# Linear Layout not visible / Overlapping

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to implement something like an action bar in android 2.2 . 
This is my main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    layout="@layout/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ScrollView    
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/dark_button"
    >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/brand_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/brand_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_button"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/car_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/car_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_button"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/model_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/model_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_button"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/location_id"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/location_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_button"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:text="@string/submit_label"
            android:textColor="@color/white"       
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_button"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />
        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/mainProgressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="gone"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_toyota"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am getting the o/p as [image: ScreenShot, Only header is visible]

I am wondering what is wrong with the code. I am new to android development. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Aman Gautam

Comment: Did you forget to explain your problem?

Comment: Ohh Sorry! I thought I must have elaborated.Only the included part is visible the main.xml. and there should be a button visible too. I don't know what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is showed in horizontal orientation because it is set by default

In root layout of **main.xml**

just put **android:orientation="vertical"**

Answer (score 2):

Instead of rolling out your own code, I highly recommend this open source project,  (https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar), I have used it in my own projects and it has worked quite well for me.

Comment: Good idea to recommend a library.  I would suggest taking a look at ActionBarSherlock instead though: http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Comment: I know the project but never tried it, is it as good as it claims? The library I recommended is quite easy to use, on the other hand ActionBarSherlock uses the same API (but different package name) as the one provided by ICS, _and_ provides much better functionality. So I think both have their merits, so you should definitely study both and decide which best suits your needs.

Comment: I've used ActionBarSherlock and it lives up to its claims.  Its highly regarded in general by Android developers.  One of the best features is that it just provides backwards compatibility with the ActionBar, so on Android 3.0 and higher devices ABS will let the native APIs take over.